# Creating x509 certificates programmatically in Objective-C using the Security Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, security

I am struggling hard to find a way to create x509 certificates programmatically (Self-signed) in Objective-C using the Security Framework. I am NOT using OpenSSL for my project. So I can't consider using OpenSSL. Here are the few things I already  created:

- Created RSA key pair. Used `- (void)generateKeyPairPlease` function per [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html)
- Used ios-csr (https://github.com/ateska/ios-csr) to create CSR. See the below code

  ```
  SCCSR *sccsr = [[SCCSR alloc]init];
  sccsr.commonName = @"some name";
  sccsr.organizationName = @"some organisation";

  NSData *certificateRequest = [sccsr build:pPublicKey privateKey:privateKey];
  NSString *str = [certificateRequest base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

  NSString *strCertificateRequest = @"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n";
  strCertificateRequest = [strCertificateRequest stringByAppendingString:str];
  strCertificateRequest = [strCertificateRequest stringByAppendingString:@"\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n"];
  ```
- Now I need to create X509 Certificate (self-signed). I used the below code.

  ```
  // Convert to Base64 data
  NSData *base64Data = [certificateRequest base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];
  SecCertificateRef cer = SecCertificateCreateWithData ( NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) base64Data);
  NSLog(@"%@", cer);
  ```
- cer seems to be NULL.`SecCertificateCreateWithData` needs "A DER (Distinguished Encoding Rules) representation of an X.509 certificate" as per [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecCertificateCreateWithData).

Is my approach correct? To reiterate: I have an RSA key pair (public and private keys), successfully generated CSR (Certificate Signing Request). Now I need the X509 Certificate to be generated programatically.

I am using version 6.2 (6C131e) and iOS SDK 8.2.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's actually possible using the Security Framework. AFAICT, the only way to do this on iOS/OSX is to use the (deprecated) CDSA library, or the (deprecated) OpenSSL library.

There is a library at https://github.com/snej/MYCrypto which can do it, but it uses some of the (deprecated) CDSA/CSSA calls, and depends on a lot of the same author's utility/library functions, which I found to be unhelpful.

I suggest you file a bug at bugreporter.apple.com to express your desire to be able to generate x.509 certificates. I have!

Edit: The MYCrypto author (snej) also has a simplified version, MYAnonymousIdentity, which takes a pre-created x.509 self-sign certificate, and uses minimum SDK calls to inject a new RSA key/signature into the existing certificate. It also used some of his utility/library stuff, but I have stripped all of that out for my own project and you can find the modified code, the script I use to generate the pre-canned certificate (and a header file containing all the offsets for modification) at: https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/tree/master/extensions/httpserver

Comment: Is it really OpneSSL is deprecated for iOS. What will happen if I will push app which is using OpenSSL?

Comment: @Ramis I'm not sure, but I believe the headers are no longer included in the SDK, so you might not be able to get as far as pushing an app!

Comment: I know this thread is old, but you are allowed to use OpenSSL – you just have to manage everything by yourself (compiling the library, including the headers). Apple says, that *they* are not providing support for OpenSSL anymore in iOS/macOS; however you are free to include it like any other external library (libsodium etc.) and you should be allowed to push those apps to the AppStore.

Comment: It's my understanding that if you don't use Apple's own encryption APIs, you'll have to deal with encryption export compliance, including if the app imports a framework that brings in custom encryption libraries, even if those encryption libraries implement recognizable standards (like OpenSSL). So it's desirable to stick with the APIs that Apple offers, especially if you're authoring a library.